# Capturing a "paste" event - or a workaround - with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, paste

I have an AJAX search script I'm making and it gives results in real time - problem is, I can't get my search function to trigger if the input is entered via right-click-paste method.

I've tried onchange and I've tried the jquery change events - nada.  Then I tried the onmouseup event but it turns out it fires outside the input element because the right-click menu extends beyond its borders if that makes sense.

I've decided I can probably accomplish this with an entire document click handler that checks for the input text element's value length being greater than 0 when it triggers, but that seems sloppy and overkill.

Does anyone has a better suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `paste` event.

```
$('input[type="text"]').bind('paste', function() { ... });
```

Comment: Wasn't aware this existed, will try asap.

Comment: You didn't close your $ parenthesis - if anyone else needs this later, be sure to add it.

Comment: Well, it seems to work if there is already text in the input box, for example if there is a name and I highlight it and right-click-paste a name in, it triggers - however, if I right-click-paste first thing before doing anything else on the page, it doesn't fire...I'm confused

Comment: Ahh, I figured it out, the paste function fires before the paste actually happens (which is why it worked when something was already in the field and then selected and pasted) so I had to add a short timeout and it works fine now, thanks for the help.